# Problem when I am running java code in the terminal in vs code

Tags: classpath

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
       // System.out.println("Hello");
        int a = 5,b=6;
        int c = a+b;
        System.out.println(c);
    } 
}
```

When I am running this code in vscode I am getting my desired result i.e. 11 but with that I am getting a huge address of a file in my local computer . Can somebody explain the reason behind that?

The output I am getting :-

**k:; cd 'k:\JavaBasics'; & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\New Folder\bin\java.exe' '-cp' 'C:\Users\khushal\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\a6084cec5acdec0bc4f5c4be0d94ed8a\redhat.java\jdt_ws\JavaBasics_22fbb3a7\bin' 'Main'
11**

I am only expecting 11 but why the address of that file

Answer (score 0):

That's the actual command that sending to the terminal. If you do not want to see them, you can update the setting `java.debug.settings.console` to `internalConsole`.

> Note: If your program needs to consume user input, you still needs to use the integrated terminal. Internal console will not work for that case.